# How to rewrite paths for file types with .htaccess? 1

Tags: .htaccess

I need to get a file who is another directory

for example `/app/uploads/file.apk`
i need it `/file/demo/file.apk`

which rule i need to use?

`RewriteRule ^file/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).([^/.]+)$` `file/viewfile.php?user=$1&name=$2  [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:

```
RewriteRule ^file/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.*\.*)$ file/viewfile.php?user=$1&name=$2  [QSA,L]
```

i guess (.*.*) is for any type file including the file name